# How can I distribute multiple concurrent requests to aws lambda functions?

Tags: go, concurrency, aws-lambda, goroutine

I want to build a cronjob like system that gets all users from database and make multiple (I mean lots of) concurrent requests for each of them and make some executions and save the result to db. It will run every hour in every day 7/24.

I came up with the solution that:

1. Gets all users from db (that's the easy part)
2. Dynamically creates lambda functions and distributes all users to these functions
3. Each lambda function makes concurrent requests and executions
   (handling results and saving them to db)
4. Communicate these functions with SNS when needed

So, does my approach make sense for this situation?

The most important thing here is scaling (that's why I thought to distribute all users to lambda functions, for limiting concurrent requests and resources), how we can come with an scalable and efficient idea for exponentially increased user count?

Or any other suggestions?

Comment: By default you cannot run more than 100 concurrent lambda functions on AWS. This limit can be lifted by submitting a request to support, but I don't think that's the best approach in your case. Do you really need to run all the requests for all users in parallel or would, say, 100 users at a time be enough? If so, there are better options than running 100 parallel lambdas.

Comment: Be careful -- your database might become a bottleneck if you suddenly hit it with hundreds of concurrent requests. Might be better to spread requests out over a period of time rather than running them all at once.

Comment: @grepe no 100 users at a time cant be enough, because its a system that tracks user activities by making some requests to apis every on hour in every day for all users, its like an analytics tool. i think 100 concurrent lambda functions with some delay optimisation would work but i am not sure

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks, i did not notice that db problem, i will think about that.

Comment: @invincible i was going to suggest you put the users on kinesis stream, take them from there in chunks and send chunks of requests to the API... but thinking about it again i will only say that it's probably time to re-design your API (or app). receiving 100,000 concurrent requests is something any reasonable sysadmin would consider a DDOS attack (btw, 65535 is maximum IP connection can handle).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

if 100 concurrent lambdas are not enough for your need, create a ticket to increase your limit, you will be charged what will you use.

However, still you can't determine that how many lambdas will be required in future. It is not necessary to process each user in a separate lambda, instead you can invoke a lambda with a chunk of user data. e.g. Let's say, your max. lambda limit is 100 and there are 1000 users then you can do something (i don't know `go`, here is a `python` code which may not be 100% syntactically correct)

```
users = get_users_fromdb()   # users = [1,2,3,... 1000]
number_of_users = len(users)
chunk_size = number_of_users / 100   # 100 is your lambda limit
for i in range(0, number_of_users, chunk_size)
    # e.g. chunk_users_data = [1,2,3 ... 10]
    chunk_users_data = users[i * chunk_size : (i + 1) * chunk_size ]
    invoke_lambda_to_process_users_chunk_data()
```

Here is what you can do in other lambda

```
users = event.get('users')
for user in users:
    try:
       process_user(user)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # handle exception / error if you want
```

### Update:

By default, 100 is limit for concurrent running lambdas. If you have 100K users, IMO, you should go for a support case to increase your account's concurrent lambda limit to 1000 or more. I am working on lambda and we have 10K limit. One more thing to keep in mind that it is not sure that your one lambda invocation will be able to process all users in a chunk, so add some logic to reinvoke with remaining users before timeout. A lambda can run upto max. of 5 minutes. YOu can get remaining time from `context` object in milli seconds.

Comment: yes, i thought the same way chunking users for each lambda. Say, i have 100.000 users and our limit 100 lambdas. So, 1k users for each lambda. Is there a max concurrent request count for a lambda ? if so, say its 10k concurrent request and our total 30k(approx.) for each, can we put a delay for each 10k and over come this limit ? minor delays are not a big deal within each request or chunk of concurrent requests.